# Crontab with sudo not working on Debian BeagleBone Black

Tags: debian, cron, users, beagleboneblack, iot

On my Beaglebone Black device, I want to run python code at startup which is shared here https://github.com/acseckin/hmrid. The python code requires super user privileges. The Debian version I used on the device was installed with the image "Debian 8.7 2017-03-19 4GB SD IOT". The code works fine from the terminal.

> sudo python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py

Debian users and roots crontab does not work when I append the following line.

> @reboot sudo python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py

But other code that does not require a super user is working perfectly when I add a crontab for a Debian user like

> @reboot python /home/debian/hmrid/runNotSuperUser.py

Comment: Why not put the code to be run as `root` into the crontab file for `root` ?

Comment: Like @thrig said: Replace sudo with root.

Comment: Yes, I am also agree with thrig. Instead of using `sudo` you can set `cron` entry for the user `root`

Comment: Also I did it but still no action

Comment: Where is the python executable? Perhaps use the fully qualified path as in `@reboot sudo /path/to/python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py`?

Comment: @Deathgrip it didnt worked for me. I think it is not about path because it is working with another code which is not needs super user privileges. I think root crontab can not start.

Comment: Per the `crontab(5)` man page, note that @reboot jobs will start when the cron daemon starts. Other daemons and facilities may not have started yet. Change the job to `@reboot sudo /path/to/python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py &>/tmp/runhmrid.out` and check the output for messages/errors.

Comment: @Deathgrip out file created (from debian users crontab) but it is empty.

Comment: Change the redirect to `>/tmp/runhmrid.out 2>&1`

Comment: @Deathgrip now it returns  as "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified"

Comment: The user with the cron job needs to be able to run command(s) with no password. Is that not the case here?

Comment: @Deathgrip How should I give super user privilges to user? here is the visudo: # User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

Comment: Suggest you study `man sudoers`. In a pinch if you're not concerned with security modify that line to `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL`. Or add a line `%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /path/to/python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py`.

Comment: I solved it with echo password | sudo -S python /.../runhmrid.py. But, now it is saying that *** buffer overflow detected ***: python terminated. Incredible it is like babushka doll

Comment: Thank to @Deathgrip for helping me find my mistake. I understand that my problem is not actually about crontab. It does not work because of the inaccuracies in the code library. here is solution https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/127#issuecomment-312410006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the job in root's crontab with `sudo crontab -e` as

```
@reboot /full/path/to/python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py
```

Be aware that the job will be executed *without* your usual environment.  This means that environment variables that may affect the way Python behaves may have to be set elsewhere for the script to work, if it relies on them somehow.

If you want to log the output from this command to a separate file, you may use

```
@reboot /full/path/to/python /home/debian/hmrid/runhmrid.py >/tmp/runhmrid.log 2>&1
```

This will log any output from the cron job to the file `/tmp/runhmrid.log` including error messages.

You may also create a shell script wrapper that sets up the environment (using a series of `export` statements) and starts you Python script. Then you may call *that* script from cron.

Comment: not worked for me. python is working. I think root crontab can not start.

Comment: @acs "Doesn't work" is not easy to debug. See update about logging and try that. Than let us know what went wrong.

Comment: Thank to @Deathgrip and you for helping me find my mistake. I understand that my problem is not actually about crontab. It does not work because of the inaccuracies in the code library. here is solution https://github.com/adafruit/adafruit-beaglebone-io-python/issues/127#issuecomment-312410006